# Can't convert Range in to Integer (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, range

I am using Ruby (1.9.3) and Rails (3.2.2). I have tasks file which contains a bunch of fake data to be populated to my database.

Here is some part of the task that I believe is causing the problem

```
#Create random Tender and populate the db
     20.times do |n|
      title  = "#{Faker::Company.bs()} tender "
      company_name = Faker::Company.name
      opening_date=Time.at(rand * Time.now.to_i)
      closing_date=Time.at(opening_date + ( 8*7*24*60*60)) #add 8 weeks to the deadline
      bid_amount= rand(10000..100000)
      description=Faker::Lorem.paragraph(sentence_count = 3)


      Tender.create!(title: title,
                   company_name: company_name,
                   opening_date: opening_date,
                   closing_date: closing_date,
           bid_amount: bid_amount    ,
           bid_amount: bid_amount    ,
           description: description )
    end
```

It works fine with dev but only the above part is not executed on production database. I am using   `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'` on dev. and

`gem 'pg', '0.12.2'` on production (heroku)

When I run

```
git push heroku
$ heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm myapp
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
$ heroku run rake db:populate

db:populate throws an error that says **can't covert Range to Integer.**
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

**EDIT:** The data type of bid_amount is `decimal`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your production ruby version is not 1.9.3. It is probably 1.8.7

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
$ irb
>> rand(10000..100000)
TypeError: can't convert Range into Integer
    from (irb):1:in `rand'
    from (irb):1
>> exit
$ rvm use 1.9.3
Using /Users/chirantan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
$ irb
1.9.3p0 :001 > rand(10000..100000)
 => 37036
```

Install ruby 1.9.3 on production and the rand method should work as expected.

Comment: Interesting, the rand() function reference doesn't mention it accepts a range at all.. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand

Comment: If you read the first line in that description, it says "If max is Range, returns a pseudorandom number where range.member(number) == true."

Comment: This doesn't say (and doesn't accept rightly) for 1.8.7 http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Kernel.html#method-i-rand

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do you install ruby on heroku even  I dont know a way to know the version on the production server. I thought it is already installed on heroku.Sorry, I am learning ruby.

Comment: And I am using Git on windows

Comment: I wish I didn't ask such a silly question but all the information I get are for Unix not for Windows.

Comment: In my gemFile i tried to put   gem 'ruby', '1.9.3' on the production grouping but it says it couldnt find that gem. Any help please?

Comment: any ways thanks. http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku/

Comment: @WowBow Another off-topic suggestion - Please switch to ubuntu or mac OS.

Comment: @Chirantan .. Once I finish my current project, I am sure I will. Luckily, I am doing better on Windows than I expected. Though, there were many challenges. To be honest I have never ever touched a mac PC. But, I tried ubuntu and even took a lot of time to install a software package. Even if it is off-topic, which one has easy learning curve for a windows developer?

Comment: from WowBow's link: specify Ruby 1.9.3 for heroku with `$ gem install bundler --pre` then add to gem file before gems `ruby '1.9.3'`, `$ bundle`